# PHP API Issue Getting No Success Message

Tags: php

I have a troubling issue in API. It is working on localhost and give success response but when I upload it server and run it in postman it is blank why?. Please help me in solving my issue

**Screen Shot 1**

[image: screen shot]

**Screen Shot 2**

[image: screen shot]

Comment: Check the server error log, you should get some clues.

Comment: If you want our help, then you need to make it _possible_ for us to help you in the first place. Please go read [ask]. We can not possibly “debug”, from the outside, what is going on here, based on only a _screenshot_ …

Comment: Please post your code.

Comment: Please post your code. Case sensitive variable name may issue

Answer (score -1):

you provide image in see the status is: **1** means **true**.

---

Your record is success fully insert.
but if your status in return any differnt number means the error